# jQuery UI toggleClass Duration Ignored

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I'm having an issue with jQuery UI's toggleClass function.  I'm using it to add a class that will apply a transition with easing when a user hovers over that element. It doesn't seem to be using the duration argument. When you mouseout, the class immediately disappears.

Libraries (both added to the head section in this order):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Function:

```
$(function() {
    $("#sidebar li").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("current-hover", 1000);
            return false;
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.nav-highlight li.current-hover a{
padding-left:1.563em;
border-left-style:solid;
border-left-color:#e42626;
-webkit-transition:padding .25s ease; /* chrome */
-moz-transition:padding .25 ease; /* firefox */
-o-transition:padding .25 ease; /* opera */
transition:padding: .25 ease;
color:#e42626;
```

}

The combination in action:  http://jsfiddle.net/ggjqb/6/